# Angular - Get array from JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Sorry for the noob question but I am just getting started with Angular. I have this array declared in services.js:

```
var articles = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Article 1 Title',
    intro: 'Article 1 Intro',
    image: 'photo.jpg',
    published: '27/10/2016',
    text: 'Article 1 Text',
    url: 'http://www.domain.com'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Article 2 Title',
    intro: 'Article 2 Intro',
    image: 'photo.jpg',
    published: '27/10/2016',
    text: 'Article 2 Text',
    url: 'http://www.domain.com'
  }];
```

Now that everything works fine in my Angular App I want to read this array from a JSON file that can be found, for example, at `www.domain.com/articles.json` and it looks like this:

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Article 1",
      "intro": "Article 1 Intro",
      "image": "image.png",
      "published": "27/10/2016",
      "text": "Article 1 Text",
      "url": "http://www.domain.com/article-1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Article 2",
      "intro": "Article 2 Intro",
      "image": "image.png",
      "published": "27/10/2016",
      "text": "Article 2 Text",
      "url": "http://www.domain.com/article-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I make this change?

Comment: articles = response.data['articles']

Comment: Have a look at the `$http` provider https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data of the file in your Angular app, you'll have to get the file's contents through an HTTP request. The easiest way to do this is by using [the `$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Example (with relative url):

```
$http.get('/articles.json').then(function (response) {
    var articles = response.data.articles;

    // Do something with articles...
});
```

The callback function you're passing to the `then` method will be called when the HTTP request was successful. Note that your data will only be available in this callback function. Also don't forget to include a dependency to the `$http` service in your controller. ;)